odoo 16 add values to Many2on field doesnt work
im trying to put values in a many2one field by code in odoo 16
what i did so far is:
ks_aus_umwandlung = fields.Boolean(string="aus Umwandlung", default=False)
ks_umwandlungs_termin = fields.Many2one('calendar.event', 
                                     store=True,compute='_umwandlungs_termine', 
                                     string"abgeschlossene Termine")


@api.depends("ks_aus_umwandlung")    
def _umwandlungs_termine(self):
related_ids = []
sql = 'select * FROM calendar_event where ks_partner_id = %s' % self.partner_id.id
list = [] 
self.env.cr.execute(sql)
list = self.env.cr.dictfetchall()
for l in list:
    related_ids.append(l['id'])
self.ks_umwandlungs_termin = [(6, 0, [related_ids])]   

   
             
in the method i get a list of values from the query, but the many2one fields is empty.
How can i pass the list of values to the Many2one field?
Thanks for any help
 

It's a many2one field, as that indicates it shall not be a list. The usual way to assign a many2one is just simply pass the id of that record.
If you are to assign a list of records, one2many shall be used. [6,0,] will replace all the existing values of this x2many relation. So use with caution.

You referenced documentation—but forgot to include the URL. I’ve edited out that reference to avoid confusion. Feel free to [edit] your post to reinclude that with the correct URL.
